# Share iCal calendar with Google Calendar

Tags: macos, google-chrome, sync, google-calendar, calendar.app

Here's a concrete problem:

I use Google Calendar and my coworker uses iCal. We need to be able to read (not write to) each others events.

I can share my different Google calendars with him by sending him the corresponding private URL, which he can then use to see my events.

However, I have not found a way to do the opposite - how can he share his calendar with me so I can see his events?

The only options I've found with Google, suggest either of us to move to either Google Calendar/iCal, which is not an option for other reasons.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30834/add-an-ical-or-.ics-calendar-to-google-calendar/

Answer (score 2):

This worked in May 2017, was broken around June 2017 and sometime recently has started working again.

It's now as easy as:

1. In Apple Calendar, click the wireless icon next to the calendar name to reveal its WebCal URL.
2. Triple click the webcal:// URL to highlight it (crappy interface!) and then copy.
3. In Google Calendar, click the "+" button next to “Add a friend's calendar” on the left side and select "From URL”.
4. Paste the URL, click "Add Calendar" and click the left arrow button in the top left corner to return to the calendar screen.

Original reference was from [How To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30834/add-an-ical-or-.ics-calendar-to-google-calendar/) but in June 2017 Google started to return

```
Settings Error Could not fetch the url.
```

Now the magic is back. Get it while it's hot.

Comment: The webcal url does not appear when clicking the wifi icon, until the calendar is marked public

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to do this and it seemed to work:

- In iCal/Calendar.app, make sure the calendar is public (ctrl-click on the calendar, sharing settings...)
- Then copy the URL of that calendar (sharing settings again)
- In Google Calendar next to **Other calendars** click the downward triangle and select **Add by URL**
- Paste in the URL from Calendar.app

That worked for me using Mac OS X 10.10.3

Comment: I already tried the same, however the URL fails to load correctly

Comment: Hmmm, does it give a particular error?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I subscribed to my own calendar in iCal, which temporarily creates a duplicate of all the events on the calendar (I know kinda' strange) and then copied the link from the subscribed calendar (not the original version that I own) and then added it to my Google calendar via the instructions shared by Heath Rafferty above, it actually shows up.  Previously I also experienced the same problem of the calendar being added but not visible, or Google Calendar getting stuck on a saving changes message that never goes away. This seems to have worked, then I just unsubscribed from my own calendar in iCal to remove the duplicate events.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, follow these instructions in order to add your Google Account to iCal: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en

After that, your Google Account will appear in the left side of the window. If you want to send any event to your Google Calendar, just drag and drop it above you Google Account name.

After that, you will be able to send him the corresponding private URL of Google Calendar.

Comment: You're describing how to share a google calender with the Apple ecosystem. The OP is asking for the opposite - sharing an apple calendar with the Google ecosystem.